# How to use the apply function for a custom function in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function

```
def cleanup_model(model, clean_model_list):
    model = model.lower()
    clean_model_list = [x.lower() for x in clean_model_list]
    for x in clean_model_list:
        if x in model:
            return x
    return model
```

I have this dataframe

```
d = {'laptops' : ['apple macbook pro 16','apple macbook', 'hp laptop xyz 15']}
a = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have this list

```
l = ['apple macbook', 'hp laptop']
```

I want to use the `apply` function in pandas to get this

```
d = {'laptops' : ['apple macbook','apple macbook', 'hp laptop xyz 15']}
a = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I am a bit confused how to apply the function above to the entire dataframe. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling `cleanup_model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to `apply` (in this case using [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)) using the `args` argument, or by passing your keyword arguments. In your case

```
def cleanup_model(model, clean_model_list):
    model = model.lower()
    clean_model_list = [x.lower() for x in clean_model_list]
    for x in clean_model_list:
        if x in model:
            return x
    return model

d = {'laptops' : ['apple macbook','apple macbook', 'hp laptop xyz 15']}
a = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
l = ['apple macbook', 'hp laptop']
a.laptops.apply(cleanup_model, args=(l,))
```

which will give you

```
0    apple macbook
1    apple macbook
2        hp laptop
Name: laptops, dtype: object
```

You can also just use keyword arguments like so

```
a.laptops.apply(cleanup_model, clean_model_list=l)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dataframe.apply(f)` is used when you have a function that takes one parameter and gives back one output

currently, your function takes in 2 parameters, so `.apply(cleanup_model)` won't work.

If you know what clean_model_list's value is before hand, I suggest doing this: (assuming that `l = ['apple macbook', 'hp laptop']` is your clean_model_list

```py
def cleanup_model(model, clean_model_list=['apple macbook', 'hp laptop']):
    model = model.lower()
    clean_model_list = [x.lower() for x in clean_model_list]
    for x in clean_model_list:
        if x in model:
            return x
    return model

a.apply(cleanup_model)
```

alternatively, you could go

```py
clean_model_list=['apple macbook', 'hp laptop']

def cleanup_model(model):
    model = model.lower()
    clean_model_list = [x.lower() for x in clean_model_list]
    for x in clean_model_list:
        if x in model:
            return x
    return model

a.apply(cleanup_model)
```